# How can I see all available params in the commands for Finder, Dock etc?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, dock

I'm trying to build my own settings script with dotfiles, like this one https://github.com/driesvints/dotfiles/blob/main/.macos

How can I see all the available parameters can be passed into

`defaults write com.apple.finder ????`

or

`defaults write com.apple.dock ???`

and/or the rest components so I can create my own script?

Comment: That's the closest thing to a published list that exists.

Comment: Is there no other available resource/link/documentation with all available options you could set??

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no command that will give you such a list.

There's also no published official documentation from Apple with such a list.

The `defaults` command essentially just writes some setting you indicate to a file. You could write anything you could come up with really, and it would still just write it to the file. It performs no checking that what you indicate is a "real" setting, nor that the value you specify is valid.

It simple writes data to a file - and gives no guarantee that the program you're trying to target will actively read that setting and use it.

You'll have to resort to the published documentation by Apple and the various scripts and forum postings you can find online with instructions on available settings you can change with the `defaults` command.

If you want to explore yourself and find "hidden" or "not well known" settings, then you can try looking inside the binaries of the programs, you mention, in order to discover new settings. If you are a software developer, you'll have tools to reverse engineer binaries that can help you a bit more - but for non-professionals, you'll probably need to resort to simple tools and lots of "trial and error". For example you can run a command like this:

```
strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

It will give you a massive list of text strings found inside the binary - some might be settings, a lot of them won't be. You can use `grep` to filter the output like this:

```
strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder | grep cmdPref
```

Which will give you a list of things to try like:

```
cmdPrefShowHardDrives:
cmdPrefShowExternalHardDrives:
cmdPrefShowRemovableMedia:
cmdPrefShowMountedServers:
cmdPrefWarnOnEmptyTrash:
```

You'll find that these correspond with settings you can modify with `defaults` under names such as `WarnOnEmptyTrash`, `ShowExternalHardDrives` and so on.

You can also look through the list of strings searching for settings you already know, and by chance nearby will be other, for you yet unknown, settings.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! ticking as correct as it was very detailed and well explained